# C++ libraries for Image Segmentation

Tags: c++, image-processing, 3d, linear-algebra

I am going to do a project in Data Mining related to image clustering (in C++) .I am looking for a powerful library which is helpful in image processing, linear algebra and 3d graphics. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is your best option in the C/C++ world in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, i think i am going to stick with OpenCV..saw its api and found it powerful...thanks.:)

Answer (score 4):

VTK is very powerful and does a lot of image processing for you.

[1]: http://www.vtk.org/ VTK

Comment: Thanks for the link..i'll check it out.

Comment: you should probably mention ITK toolkit (Insight Segmentation and Registration Toolkit) instead which does the actual image segmentation. Both are from the same company.
Link to Wiki:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/ITK

Answer (score 2):

How about Image Magic. It is very mature and can manipulate just about any image type.
There are multiple API's including a C++ one:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick%2B%2B/

Comment: Image magick is very good for image manipulation / enhancement, but not suitable for image analysis and general data extraction tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I second openCV, but I don't think there's any 3d graphics in it. Also openCV 2.0 is coming out [any day now](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV200906).

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on Image Segmentation during my Masters Project , I would suggest you

C++ Based

- ITK: http://www.itk.org/
- CImg: http://cimg.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

seg-ijcv works great, it does graph based segmentation, works fast, written in C++.

http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~pff/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf